# Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with this php conditional

Tags: php, html, authentication, credentials

I'm trying to do a really simple login system using php.  I have two files at the moment:  index.php and verifyCredentials.php

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test Site</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to My Test Homepage!</h1>

        <?php if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != "true") : ?>
            <form method="post" action="verifyCredentials.php">
                Username: <input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" value=""/><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/><br>
            </form>
        <?php else : ?>
            <h2>You're logged in! :)</h2>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if($_GET['verferr']==1){echo "<b>Login failed: incorrect username or password.</b>";} ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**verifyCredentials.php**

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username == "myusername" && $password == "letmein")
    {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = "true";
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $loginfailed_param = "?verferr=1";
        header("Location: index.php" . $loginfailed_param);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

I've successfully made it so that if your username/password were incorrect (i.e. not equal to `myusername` and `letmein`), then it redirects to the login page and echo's an error message under the form.

I'm trying to make it so that when they do verify that the form on index.php, the form disappears and is replaced with some success text.  But, when I type in myusername and letmein, it just redirects to the login without an error and the form still showing.

From the research I've done, I'm required to use the if-else php structure as shown in my index.php file if I want to have html in between my php nodes, but am I doing this incorrectly?

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP Sessions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) require that you call `session_start()` at the top of every page where you use `$_SESSION`. I don't see it in your example.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use sessions to store data make sure you have `session_start();` at the top of every page you call. Otherwise it won't read in the session identifier and will assume you want to start a new one.

So at the top of your `index.php` and `verifyCredentials.php` add the command. But make sure you have it as the first line of code on the page. You will then need to add it to any page that is directly requested.

For example, if you have `index.php` and it includes `form.php` and `nav.php`, then only `index.php` will need the `session_start()`, but if you have a link to `form_processing.php`, then `form_processing.php` will need to have `session_start()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Aww, you accepted right as I had this ready.  :(

Here is  what you need to use. anyway.. 
(Also, you should use jQuery for better transitional effects, see below)

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    $args = array(
        'username'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS,
        'password'    => FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

    if ($post) {

        $username = $post['username'];
        $password = $post['password'];

        if($username == "myusername" && $password == "letmein") {

            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;

        } else {

            $loginfailed_param = "?verferr=1";
            header("Location: index.php" . $loginfailed_param);
            exit;
        }
    }

    if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] === true) {

        //User has logged in

    }

    ?>
```

> Using jQuery

**HTML**

```
<div id="loginForm">

    <form id="myLoginForm">
        <input id="username">
        <input id="password">
        <button id="formSubmit" name="formSubmit">Submit Form</button>
        <input style="display: none;" type="text" id="realSubmit" name="realSubmit" value="hidden">
    </form>

</div>
<div id="successPage">

   Thank you for loggging in...

</div>
<div id="loginHome">
    Login Homepage
    Welcome <span id="displayUsername"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function($){
    $(function(){

        $("#formSubmit").on('click', function() {



            var username= $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var data = {username: username, password: password};
            delegateAjax('../myAjax.php', data, 'POST');

        });
    });

function delegateAjax(url, data, responseType, dataType, callback) {

    function successHandler(data) {
        console.log("Ajax Success");
        var responseData = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (responseData.status === 'Success') {

            $("#loginForm").fadeOut(1500, function() {
                 $("#successPage").fadeIn(1500, function() {
                     $(this).fadeOut(1500, function() {

                         $("#displayUsername").html(responseData.username);
                         $("#loginHome").fadeIn(1500);
                     });
                 });
            });
        }
    };

    function failureHandler(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("Ajax Error");
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
        console.dir(xhr);
    };

    function handler404(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("404 Error");
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
        console.dir(xhr);
    };

    function handler500(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("500 Error");
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
        console.dir(xhr); 
    };

    url = typeof url !== 'undefined' ? url : 'js/ajaxDefault.php';
    data = typeof data !== 'undefined' ? data : new Object();
    responseType = typeof responseType !== 'undefined' ? responseType : 'GET';
    dataType = typeof dataType !== 'undefined' ? dataType : 'json';
    callback = typeof callback !== 'undefined' ? callback : 'callback';

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: url, type: responseType, cache: true, data: data, dataType: dataType, jsonp: callback, 
                        statusCode: { 404: handler404, 500: handler500 }});
    jqxhr.done(successHandler);
    jqxhr.fail(failureHandler);
};

})(jQuery);
```

**PHP**

*myAjax.php*

```
<?php

define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if (!IS_AJAX) {
    $response['status'] = 'Error';
    $response['message'] = 'Same Origin Policy Error';
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
$pos = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], getenv('HTTP_HOST'));
if ($pos === false) {
    $response['status'] = 'Error';
    $response['message'] = 'Same Origin Policy Error';
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

function validUser($data) {
    //connect to db and validate user
    $dbi = new mysqliObject();
    $params['string'] = $data['username'];
    $dbi->newSelect($params);
    $table = 'users';
    $select = '*';
    $where = '`username` = ? LIMIT 1';
    if ($dbi->exec($table, $select, $where)) {
        $result = $dbi->result[0];
        return passwordVerify($result['password']); //true/false
    } else {

        //for debugging
        //echo 'Last Error: '.$dbi->get('lastError').'<br>'."\r\n";
        //echo 'Last Query: '.$dbi->get('lastQuery').'<br>'."\r\n";
        return false;
    }
}

$args = array(
    'username'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS,
    'password'    => FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

$post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

if ($post) {



    if (validUser($post)) {


        $response['status'] = 'success';
        $response['username'] = $username;

        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;

    } else {

        $response['status'] = 'Failed';
        $response['message'] = 'Username/Password Invalid';
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }
}

$response['status'] = 'Error';
$response['message'] = 'POST Data Invalid';
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```